# How to create a two-level-dictionary from one file?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a csv file that looks like this (in reality it is bigger):

```
country;company1;company2;company3
finland;30;30;40
sweden;20;30;50
norway;10;20;70
```

How could I read this file the easiest, so that I could get a dictionary like this (dictionaries inside a dictionary):

```
{ 'company1': {'finland': 30, 'sweden': 20, 'norway': 10}
'company2': {'finland': 30, 'sweden': 30, 'norway': 20}
... 
}
```

I first tried to make a separate list from the first of the file, aka from the companies, then created a dictionary from them. But then I ran into problems while trying to read the lines after the first one and create a dictionary inside the already created one.

I'm sorry if the explanation is bad, I'm new to coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@fsimonjetz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68741295/1453822) is great if you are already working with pandas in this project. If you are not, using it just for this task is a huge overkill, as we can parse and transpose the data with a simple logic.

```
import csv

from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(dict)

with open('path/to/your.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    companies = reader.fieldnames[1:]
    for line in reader:
        country = line['country']
        for company in companies:
            output[company][country] = line[company]
            # or output.setdefault(company, {})[country] = line[company]
            # if you want 'output' to be a "normal" dict instead of defaultdict

print(dict(output))  # or just print(output) if you don't mind seeing OrderedDict
                     # repr
```

outputs

```
{'company1': {'finland': '30', 'sweden': '20', 'norway': '10'}, 
 'company2': {'finland': '30', 'sweden': '30', 'norway': '20'}, 
 'company3': {'finland': '40', 'sweden': '50', 'norway': '70'}}
```

Comment: Yes I am not yet familiar with pandas. But thank you very much, this solved it! And I learned something new :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), which is a good idea anyway if you need to work with tabular data:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('path/to/your.csv', delimiter=';', index_col='country')
>>> df.to_dict()
{'company1': {'finland': 30, 'sweden': 20, 'norway': 10},
 'company2': {'finland': 30, 'sweden': 30, 'norway': 20},
 'company3': {'finland': 40, 'sweden': 50, 'norway': 70}}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think using an OrderedDict would help a lot. You could do it in a way similar as this:

```py
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    list_companies = next(reader)  # ['country', 'company1', 'company2', ...]
    companies_dict = OrderedDict()
    for company in list_companies[1:]:  # We forget about 'country'
        companies_dict[company] = {}  # We initialize the companies' dicts in order
    for country_values in reader:  # For every line after the first one
        country = country_values[0]  # We get the country at the beginning of every line
        for countries_dict, value in zip(companies_dict.values(), country_values[1:]):
            countries_dict[country] = value  # And set the value for every company in order

    print(dict(companies_dict))
    # {'company1': {'finland': '30', 'sweden': '20', 'norway': '10'}, ...}
```

The `zip` function might be new to you, it's a generator that basically takes two (or more) iterables and puts the elements in the same position together as a set. For example, `zip(['finland', 'sweden' , 'england'], [30, 30, 40]) == [('finland', 30), ('sweden', 30), ('england', 40)]`

This might not be exactly correct for your purpose but I believe it's a good enough approach to what you want to achieve.

Comment: 1. `reader.next()` should be `next(reader)` 2. This does not really provide the correct output

Comment: @DeepSpace 1. You're right, I wasn't thinking in python3. 2. But it does? I've tested it and the contents of `companies_dict` are `{'company1': {'finland': '30', 'sweden': '20', 'norway': '10'}, 'company2': {'finland': '30', 'sweden': '30', 'norway': '20'}, 'company3': {'finland': '40', 'sweden': '50', 'norway': '70'}}`